# Jquery get attribute ID for latest click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

im trying to get the attribute value through jquery

```
$(document).click(function() {                                    
            var elem = $("input[name='phone']");
            alert(elem.length);
            if(elem.length > 0){
                  alert(elem.attr('id'));
                }
            });
```

here the case is

i have lots of input fields with same name as "phone" in different form. Whenever i click it i can get only the first value. Not the last one. How can i get it through the Jquery.

In my page only document click will work because the form codes are loading from some other site.

Any help is more appreciate

Comment: Use `$(event.target).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $( "input[name^='phone']" ).last()
```

will return the last element with name beginning with 'phone'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, to get the id of the item that is clicked.

```
$("input[name='phone']").click(function() {      
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

This is attaching the listener to phone inputs and `this` is the context, which in this case the item that is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='phone']").on('focus', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will listen to clicks on your `phone` input fields and alert the `id` attribute for you to see on screen:

**JQuery**

```
$("input[name='phone']").click(function() {                                    
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**HTML example**

```
<input id="a" name="phone">A</input>
<input id="b" name="phone">B</input>
<input id="c" name="phone">C</input>
<input id="d" name="phone">D</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate the event with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), then you can use `this`:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="phone"]', function() {
  console.log('element with id: ' + this.id + ' has value: ' + this.value);
});
```